# "We are to be men of steel and ice and walk immune amidst the suppuration of the Earth" Which story?

Tags: story-identification, books

"We are to be men of steel and ice and walk immune amidst the suppuration of the Earth"
This quote is from an sf story I read when I was a child and I've never been able to find it again. Does anyone have an idea where it comes from?

Comment: And when was 'when I was a child' ?  Any other details beyond the quote ?  You must have some ideas because you state that it was a SF story.

Comment: It's a long time ago! A classic sf novel or short story from the 1970's. This has bothered me for years. Someone must remember such a striking phrase, surely?

Comment: The impression I get from the quote is that it could be from characters from a rigid/conservative/religious society coming to a cosmopolitan earth. Unfortunately, that isn't very specific.

Comment: It could be. My very vague memory is that these are cyborgs, half human, half machine moving through an Earth ravaged by some apocalyptic disaster.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "suppuration of the earth" has one Google hit other than this question. It's from a book about the works of David Rudkin:

http://books.google.com/books?id=OXNTAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=%22suppuration+of+the+Earth%22&source=bl&ots=uJSiPAqNLi&sig=uJzxaqkn-1IGxgQeuwKhccdU1EA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XPOjUrfwGMjMsATLr4CACw&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22suppuration%20of%20the%20Earth%22&f=false

As you can see, the partial quote mentioning that phrase also mentions immunity: "Searching the corridors, Gideon finds Jed in one cell... bowed by the weight of his head 'keeping all [his] foulness in', fixed on immunity from 'the suppuration of the earth'."

From what I gather, this would be from Rudkin's "Sons of Light," which seems to be a play. It's not much to go on, but it may be a clue for you or others.

Comment: Thanks you for the insight. Certainly this is an unusual phrase and I'm wondering if it has an origin independent of the story in my recollection.